# Using first 4 characters of file name to create unique list

Tags: bash, ubuntu, uniq

I primarily use Linux Mint 17.1 and I like to use command line to get things done.
At the moment, I am working on organising a whole lot of family pictures and making them easy to view via a browser.
I have a directory with lots of images.
As I was filling the directory I made sure to keep the first four letters of the filename unique to a specific topic, eg, car_, hse_, chl_ etc
The rest of the filename keeps it unique.
There are some 120 different prefixes and I would like to create a list of the unique prefix.
I have tried 'ls i | uniq -d -w 4' and it works but it gives me the first filename of each prefix.
I just want the prefixes.
Fyi, I will use this list to generate an HTML page as a kind of catalogue.
Summary,
Convert car_001,car_002,car_003,dog_001,dog_002
to
car_,dog_

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$ ls -1 | cut -c1-3 | sort -u
```

uses the first 3 chars of the file names.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
ls -1 | cut -d'_' -f1 | uniq | sort
```

where cut splits the text by _ and takes the first field of each.